# Program can't kill() processes when launched from boot script

Tags: c, linux

I'm sure my question has probably been answered previously but I didn't find anything specific to my situation after searching for a while.

**Background:**

I have written a suite of data acquisition tools in C that run on an embedded system running Debian Wheezy. There is a main module, called Dispatch, whose job is to launch the rest of the modules and pass messages between them. I put a trivial bash script in `/etc/init.d` that executes Dispatch when the system boots since this system runs unattended. This system runs without any local user interaction so Dispatch should really be written to function as a daemon but it is not. The startup script simply executes `/opt/bcdispatch &`.

There's a bug in one of the other modules that causes it to crash every few days. I'm trying to hunt down that bug but in the meantime I am trying to write a watchdog program that will detect the crash, kill off all of my processes, then relaunch Dispatch. For reasons I won't go into it is not sufficient to just relaunch the crashed process, the whole suite of tools needs to be restarted.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I wrote a simple watchdog program that periodically executes `popen("ps aux | grep bc")` (all of my process names start with "bc" which makes it easy to find them with grep), finds that one of the modules has crashed by looking for anything with a "zombie" status in any of the lines read from `popen()`, kills all of my processes by calling `system("kill <PID>")`, then executes the startup script in `/etc/init.d` and exits. I modified the startup script so that it launches the watchdog after launching Dispatch. The startup script now looks like:

`/opt/bcdispatch &
/opt/mywatchdog &`

Everything is being run as root. There are no other user accounts on the system.

**Problem**

The watchdog process works fine if I run it from the command line. It kills off all of the processes it's supposed to, launches the startup script, then exits. However, when the watchdog is launched by the startup script at boot time it doesn't do its thing. It's running, one of the processes it's monitoring has crashed, but it doesn't kill the rest of them off. It just sits there like a giant turd. I can start another instance of it from the command line and that one works just fine.

**Question**

So my question (finally!) is: why can't my program kill other processes when launched via a startup script? I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the watchdog process no longer has a terminal associated with it? I tried substituting the call to `system("kill <PID>")` with `kill(PID)` but that didn't change anything.

**EDIT**

It just occurred to me that it's not the kill()ing part that doesn't work (well, that might be broken as well), the call to popen("ps aux | grep bc") must not be working since the watchdog should exit after it finds the zombie process but it isn't. Its PID is still the same as it was when the system booted. I guess this means the title of this question isn't very good.

Comment: Under what user is the program running? Does it have the right do `kill` the other process? If you use [the `kill` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html), what error does it return (i.e. if it fails and return `-1` then what is the value of [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html))?

Comment: See my edit: it appears kill isn't really the problem. But to answer your questions everything is running as root.

Comment: How about you show the code? Might help us help you :). Also, if you're writing in C, I would rather not use external commands. It's slow and brittle as their output might change. You could get your processes by reading `/proc/*/exe`. And if you have errors, you can reliably know when and what.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. The output of my watchdog's call to `popen("ps aux | grep bc")` was being truncated to 80 columns, presumably because it was no longer attached to a terminal and that's the default terminal width. That truncation was causing problems for the way the program was parsing the results of the `ps` command so it never found the crashed process. Changing the command to `popen("ps -w aux | grep bc")` was all that was needed to fix it.